# handlebars в блоке #if не видно булевое значение helper функции

Tags: if, handlebars

Срабатывает else, хотя функция возвращает true. И, даже, если функция возвращает строку "true", должно срабатывать как true, но как false:

```
    {{#if isJSON}}
        KKK
    {{else}}
        ggg {{isJSON}} <!-- true -->
    {{/if}}
```

helper функция

```
module.exports () => {
    return true;
};
```

Comment: Укажите в метках язык, а то не особо понятно..

Comment: @Zicrael
handlebars - это как бы html+js шаблоны

Comment: выглядит ужасно. Для такого Angular нужно юзать я думаю.  Сейчас напишу ответ.

Comment: @Zicrael да, ужасно! очень корявая вещь этот handlebars! Pug(jade) несравненно лучше, ну, или js-фреймворк.я бы node.js + pug использовал лучше.

Answer (score 1):

```
{{#if !!isJSON}} <!-- Попробуйте так -->
    KKK
{{else}}
    ggg {{isJSON}} <!-- true -->
{{/if}}
```

Comment: спасибо, но не работает. там все сложнее и замутно. вроде, видил решение свой if писать как бы, но мне не вариант то. !! не разрешает использовать. есть еще {{#unless но соти не меняет.

Comment: Я так понимаю isJSON равняется результату helper функции?

Comment: да, isJSON - имя той функции. я для теста просто делаю return true; так и выводит, только почему-то {{#if не видит как будто то значение правильно.

Comment: У меня есть подозрение что функция не отрабатывает , либо отрабатывает позже. Поставьте `debugger;` внутри `helper` функции?

Comment: {{#if isJSON}} здесь отрабатывает, проверил.

Comment: Мне кажется вам стоит сделать переменную с типом boolean и уже ею оперировать из функции, так как if скорее всего интерпретирует isJSON явно не в boolean. Попробуйте

Comment: const a = true; console.log('oooooooooo' + a); return a; при вызове в {{#if в консоль пишет верное значение - true. выглядит, как глюк самого handlebars

Comment: Очень странно, я бы посоветовал на будущее для таких дел использовать `Angular`. Или любой другой `js` фреймворк. Если честно у меня нет идей.

Comment: спасиБо! нашел чуть другое решение в обход: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37935632/873481 - так работает (а с тем не понятно...)

Comment: Жесть:)) Ну ты в следующий раз так не извращайся, лучше используй фреймворки, они то хоть проверены и костыли искать не надо:)

Comment: да... я бы никогда и не взялся за это, но тест задание делаю, где это используют. Надеюсь убедить потом перейти на что-то нормальное.
вот еще дополнение qaru.site/questions/438961/handlebars-custom-if-helper-else-is-undefined - пусть уже будет здесь.

Comment: Да , пусть останется, может кто то наткнётся и не будет делать сколько попыток как мы :D